# Ruby on Rails 4 - simple_form multiple select input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a simple_form input field that looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :particular_users, collection: @all_users, input_html: { class: 'multiselectuser', multiple: true} %>
```

When I leave multiple: true off, the form submits the chosen value for the parameter :particular_users and I can see the value when debugging using "raise params.inspect". However when I leave the multiple: true option there, no vales get passed for the parameter :particular_users.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I can not use the association input because :particular_users is a virtual attribute  and has no relationship. I want the multiple select box to pass whatever values that are in there, even if they are arbitrary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It actually does work the way I wanted it to. The trick is to tell the strong parameters to allow a hash. It doesn't throw a strong parameters error, the param just gets thrown out and doesn't come through. So I set it to for example: params.require(:survey).permit(:particular_users => []).

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have an array whitelisted in my strong params but cannot figure this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627957/rails-5-acts-as-taggable-on-gem-form-select-for-defined-tag-lists/41628074?noredirect=1#comment70459089_41628074

Answer (score 60):

```
f.input :days, collection: @your_collection, input_html: { multiple: true }
```

Comment: can you explain what you are doing here. that would help out a lot

Comment: if you use simple_form gem and want multiple select just add this attribute to input_html

Comment: For some reason, it is not allowing to unselect.

Answer (score 4):

To create multiple select tags with `simple_form`, use:

```
<%= f.association :particular_users, collection: @all_users, input_html: { class: 'multiselectuser'} %>
```

see part `Associations` in the [gem description](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

But as you don't want to use an ActiveRecord associaion, use `select_tag`:

```
<%= select_tag 'particular_users', 
       options_from_collection_for_select(@all_users, :id, :name), 
       multiple: true, class: 'multiselectuser' %>
```

Comment: I receive the error: Association :particular_users not found because :particular_users is a virtual attribute and not an association. I don't want to select an association, I just want the params to pass what is in the multiple select box even if they are arbitrary values.

Comment: then simple_form is not the right tool for you. Use `select_tag` to build your custom select.

Comment: It is actually what I want. I posted the correct answer.