# How can I change how collections are stored through Simple Form?

Tags: ruby, simple-form

I want to return on a view the users whose interest_category selections match my own 100% on at least 1 interest_category. If users don't match on at least 1 interest_category, they should not be selected.

Apart from the 100% matches, my view should show sorted by match rate.

For instance, if I select 5 interest_category items, and another **user A** has at least 5 of her interest_category items which are equal to mine, this is a 100% match.

If a **user B** has 4 interests which are equal to mine, this is a 4/5 (80%) match.

Each user edits its' profile with a Simple Form. I'm posting part of it here:

```
<%= f.input :interest_category, collection: ['Reading', 'Tech' ,'Food', 'Mindfullness', 'Sports', 'Parenting', 'Yoga'], input_html: { multiple: true }, include_blank: true, include_hidden: false, label: "Select your interest: "%>
```

Which, after selecting the first 3 options, stores the following into the DB:

**"[\"Reading\", \"Tech\", \"Food\"]"**

I have started to define a new method on my Users controller called **matches** which should have the matching logic to select my matched users.

Would someone be able to help me out on understanding how to go ahead and think about this?

**EDITED**

So, I was able to resolve this by adding a method on my Users controller and work from there with IFs on first defining a variable that would get me the common elements:

```
join_categories = match_real_categories & user_real_categories
```

and then playing around with the .length, calculating a ratio between common  elements and both match or user elements:

```
      match_real_categories = match.interest_category.gsub(/[~;:"'<>?#\s\]\\\[]+/, '').split(",")
      user_real_categories = @user.interest_category.gsub(/[~;:"'<>?#\s\]\\\[]+/, '').split(",")
      join_categories = match_real_categories & user_real_categories
      join_length = join_categories.length

      if join_categories.length == 0
        match_value = 0
      elsif match_real_categories.sort == user_real_categories.sort
        match_value = 1
      else
        match_value = join_categories.length.to_f*2 / (user_real_categories.length.to_f + match_real_categories.length.to_f)
      end
```

Comment: You'll need an onclick function that triggers each time you check a box. This function would take your current checked boxes and call the your `matches` method and rerender your view.

A screenshot of what your form looks like and what you want would help a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails 4 - simple\_form multiple select input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159614/ruby-on-rails-4-simple-form-multiple-select-input)

Comment: Hi @JosephCho, thanks for that. So the view render will only happen later on. Take this form as a profile edit form. Form and Render view are totally independent.